# Using TypeKit locally on a NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typekit

I can't seem to get TypeKit working on my local node webserver.

I've added `localhost` and `localhost:1337` to my list of domains (not sure if the one with the port is making a difference though).

The webserver is running on 1337, it has the typekit script with the correct kit ID, but the typekit .js library always comes back with 404.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this issue?  I have the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are clicking the green 'Publish' button after editing your Kit Setting Domains (after clicking 'Save Settings'). If you don't do this, "Changes won’t be live on your site until you publish them."

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I could not get Typekit to work on localhost just by adding `localhost` to the list of domains (reason is still unknown to me, decided not to care too much about it).

What I ended up doing as a quick solution is just set a wildcard to my list of domains in Typekit so instead of having:

`staging.mysite.com`

I set:

`*.mysite.com`

Then, on my own computer i added a non existing subdomain to my `/etc/hosts`, ie:

`$ sudo vim /etc/hosts`

(opens my Host Database configuration)

At the end of the file I added:

`127.0.0.1 localdev.mysite.com`

Opening `localdev.mysite.com:8000` now shows my working copy without the annoying 403 error I previously had (not 404 as in your case). I hope this will prove helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a `404` error, then you have not published your kit.

If you are getting a `403` error, then you need to whitelist your domain (without a specified port -- localhost:8080 becomes localhost).

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2077663